# Create a Spring Framework starter project, not Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a project that uses Spring Framework `3.2.11.RELEASE` version and we want to implement some new stuff in it, but before I want to make a small Rest API so I can do a proof of concept application. This small Rest API must use the same packages as the original one (no, updating the main project is not an option).

When using https://start.spring.io/ it gives me a good project but using Spring boot, which is not what I want. Using the project Initialzr gave me I changed the `pom.xml` to use the same spring packages of the original project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Now I'm trying to modify the starter class to work with the dependencies in the `pom.xml`. This is where I'm lost, so far I couldn't find anything similar in the main project or the web. So, how could I change this main class so I can get it working?

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't added any BusinessLogic to your current `SpringBoot` application, then you can create new Spring project using `Eclipse` or `STS` IDE. Your tester or main class will look something like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  
  
public class Test {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
      
    Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");  
    student.displayInfo();  
}  
}
```

(I have `Student` class created in my IDE that's why using an instance of that class just for DEMO)
And your `.xml` file should look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <beans  
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  
      
    <bean id="studentbean" class="com.app.Student">  
    <property name="name" value="Student1"></property>  
    </bean>  
      
    </beans>
```

I hope this will somehow help you!